# Use of SharePoint "lookup". How to make a sub level menu with Lookup how to make

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup, getjson

I want to make a drop-down menu. I'm bringing the top menu, but I can not figure out how to get the bottom menu. I am trying to do it with Sharepoint lookup. When you review the screenshots, you will understand what I mean. I'm sorry for the bad english.

Image link adress: https://i.hizliresim.com/3ppJ4O.png

Example i try to do: https://i.hizliresim.com/d77E9Z.png